# Building Elsa on windows

Tags: c++, windows, parsing, porting

How would I build elsa under windows?

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~smcpeak/elkhound/sources/elsa/

A visual studio would be preferable or something I can link with using visual studio,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compile it under Cygwin.

Download the Cygwin install, select GCC and Flex, Perl, etc. Install that stuff, then follow the normal build process, once in Cygwin.

Comment: cygwin is not an option. It is too invasive and the installer will not download files due to network policies, and the chances of these policies changing are next to impossible.

Comment: Do you want to have a one off build or be able to rebuild?